# Finding duplicate values in a SQL table and group by creation date

Tags: sql, oracle

What's the simplest SQL statement that will return the duplicate values for a given column for example `ORDERS_NUMBERS` and group it by oldest `CREATION_DATE` in an Oracle database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   ORDER_NUMBERS, count(*)
FROM     YourTableName
GROUP_BY ORDER_NUMBERS
HAVING   count(*) > 1
ORDER BY CREATION_DATE
```

Comment: Is `GROUP_BY` really works - instead of `GROUP BY` - !?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ORDERS_NUMBERS,CREATION_DATE,count(*)
from
table
group by ORDERS_NUMBERS,CREATION_DATE
order by CREATION_DATE desc 
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
t.orders_numbers, 
t.creation_date

from table t
group by t.orders_numbers, 
t.creation_date
having (count (*) >1)
;
```